# How do I assign a excel.worksheet object to a worksheet that I've just copied (all in one go)

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a copy of an Excel worksheet that I want to assign to another Excel worksheet object , but the Excel copy method doesn't return anything so I can't assign an object to it all in one line. This is what I was hoping to do:

```
    wksTarget = wksSource.Copy(After:=wkbExperiment.Sheets(wkbExperiment.Sheets.Count))
```

...but this gives me "Expression does not produce a value"

So I have to do this instead:

```
    wksSource.Copy(After:=wkbExperiment.Sheets(wkbExperiment.Sheets.Count))
    wksTarget = wkbExperiment.Sheets(wkbExperiment.Sheets.Count)
```

which is relying on the copied sheet being the last one which isn't as nice.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Kristian

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, you have to replace your last line with

```
Set wksTarget = wkbExperiment.Sheets(wkbExperiment.Sheets.Count)
```

I do not know why you call it "not as nice", since it does exactly what you mean to.

You can use, alternatively,

```
Dim wksLoc As Sheet
Set wksLoc = wkbExperiment.Sheets(wkbExperiment.Sheets.Count)
wksSource.Copy(After:=wksLoc)
Set wksTarget = wksLoc.Next
```

Comment: Hi Sanchos.s - my second block of code works without the set, but I don't like having to rely on sheet order when assigning a sheet to an object, so If I can do it all in one line, then there is no chance the object is assigned to the wrong sheet. My workbook uses lots of sheets and I can't name them easily as the 23 character limit causes too many problems.

Comment: @Kristian - A few comments: 1) I think there is no alternative method that copies a `Worksheet` and returns the copied object, so it would not be possible to do it "in one go". 2) I do not know why you think "there is a chance the object is assigned to the wrong sheet", with either of the alternative code snippets. You are unequivocally identifying the `Worksheet` after which you will create your new one, and using a reference to the following one. You could go wrong only if you insert code in-between. If that is what you fear, use multiple sentences in a single line, with colon(s).